# Powershell automatically using new line

Tags: xml, powershell, output, autosize

I'm in trouble with my script.

I'm grabbing paths out of an XML-File, that need to be modified.

```
$file = [xml](Get-Content "PATH\TO\XML.xml")

$file.here.is.my.attribute  | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize | out-file -filepath ".\PATHS.txt" -append
```

Powershell is inserting line-breaks in the middle of my path, because it's to long (Just read about buffersize). I tried to save it to an .XML File instead of an .TXT File but that didn't work for me.

Any Idea of a workaround?

File should look like this:

```
Path1\Path\Path\path  
Path2\Path\Path\path  
Path3\Path\Path\path
```

But it looks like:

```
Path1\Path\Path\  
path  
Path1\Path\Path\  
path  
Path1\Path\Path\  
path
```

XML-Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend>
  <servicing>
    <package>
      <assemblyIdentity/>
      <source location="HERE\IS\MY\PATH"/>
    </package>
    <package>
      <assemblyIdentity/>
      <source location="HERE\IS\ANOTHER\PATH"/>
    </package>
    <package>
      <assemblyIdentity/>
      <source location="HERE\IS\ANOTHER\PATH"/>
    </package>
  </servicing>
</unattend>
```

Comment: and why precisely do you think you need to pipe Format-Table to Out-File? shouldnt it be either-or?

Comment: I used it to format the line automatically to the right length. But "autosize" is at its maximum

Comment: I thought it's necessary to pre-format my data...

Comment: You shouldn't output Format-table to a file

Comment: You only need to format your data depending on how you want it formatted. `Format-Table` is just for console output not for files

Comment: okay, thank you, but that does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Matt Will try this right now..

Comment: Who are you responding to? Also can you show a sample of the output you are expecting in your question? `-Width` was a bad suggestion. It will truncate the output.

Comment: well, tell us what do you want your txt to look like?

Comment: It should look like: 
PATH1\a\b\c
PATH2\a\b\c

Now it looks like:
Path1\a
\b\c
Path2\a\
b\c

okay I can't show this in comments. Moments please...

Comment: @DanielGroß You need to add that into the question to be sure about the formatting. In comments something could easily be lost. See the edit button below your question.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, this is my first post, I added it to my question.

Comment: all in a single line?

Comment: Good work. What happens if you just run this: `$file.here.is.my.attribute | Set-Content ".\PATHS.txt"`. If I am wrong I would want to see a sample of the xml to be sure.

Comment: @JaquelineVanek one path/line. Please take a look onto my edit in the question.

Comment: @matt The Path.txt contains "System.Xml.XmlElement" repeatet over lines.

Comment: I edited a minimalistic edit of my XML-File.

Comment: Are there multiples <package> elements in one <servicing>? Either way I can pull out that one with `$xml.unattend.servicing.package.source.location` You can get the attributes via dot notation as well.

Comment: Yes there are multiple <package> elements. And I need all of them.

Comment: you might be missing a ".location" at the end of "$file.here.is.my.attribute" -- not accessing the attribute value properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `Format-Table` is merely for console output. Trying to use for anything other than that will cause you issues. Given your sample XML you can just use dot notation to get all `location`'s

In your example you were trying to output an object array with a `location` property. Calling the attribute using dot notation removes that layer from the output.

```
$xmlFile = [xml](Get-Content "PATH\TO\XML.xml")
$xmlFile.unattend.servicing.package.source.location | Set-Content ".\PATHS.txt"
```

I don't think you actually needed to be appending to the file in this case. However if you really are building a larger file then you can use `Add-Content` in place of `Set-Content` in my example.

**Sample Output**

```
HERE\IS\MY\PATH
HERE\IS\ANOTHER\PATH
HERE\IS\ANOTHER\PATH
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I nearly spend hours on that issue. :-)